# Is there a need of Page - ContentType and Page - PageEncoding attribute?

Tags: jsp

Whenever I create a new `JSP` page on `NetBeans` there is this default file structure which includes the following among other things:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          .....
```

Nothing redundant except for the fact content type and page encoding is specified twice (I think so) in the `<%@page ...>` directive and then `<meta>` tag. 
So my question is that whether there is a need to specify the page directive's `contentType` and `pageEncoding` attribute?

Comment: No there is no forced need to let those lines in your project just for setting a default template that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need both

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html"  pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

is sufficient it implicitly set the response header

#### ContentType charset

The contentType charset is how the servlet container which runs the JSP must send to the browser the text generated by the page.

#### PageEncoding

The pageEncoding directive is used to correctly read the JSP from the file system. Since even the JSP is a text but a file is a sequence of bytes on disk, it can be correctly read only knowing the charset to use.

[source](http://www.satollo.net/jsp-and-the-content-type-charset-and-the-page-encoding-attribute)